# How to compile inline C function with literal attributes with GCC?

Tags: c, function, gcc, compiled, inline-functions

I have an `inline` function like this:

```
inline void func_1 (int a)
{
   if(a==1)
   {
      other_func1();
   }
   else
   {
      other_func2();
   }
}
```

and I use in the Main like this:

```
 int main()
 {
     func1(1);
     func1(42);

     return 0;
 }
```

I use GCC, I think, the compiled code look like this (in “source level”):

```
 int main()
 {
     other_func1()
     other_func2();

     return 0;
 }
```

Is it true or am I wrong?

Comment: If you're not sure what compiler generates, you can always use `-S` (and maybe `-fverbose-asm` for better readability) and check generated assembly. Result may be different for different compiler options and optimisation levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in general gcc will optimise away dead code in inline functions when it can evaluate branches at compile-time. I use this construct a lot to allow optimised code to be generated for different use cases - somewhat like template instantiation in C++.